# Running script on profile.d with gsettings problems when ssh

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 for a computer that will have multiple users. I have configured the following:

/etc/profile.d/all_users.sh

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino disable-background true
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods "['none']"
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

This works great. As all users get this settings when they log in.

The problem is when I ssh to this machine. I get errors like:

> dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch
>   D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

So I am wondering if anybody knows how I can:

- Avoid running the profile.d script when I ssh into this machine
- configure the the profild.d script so that it detects that it's an ssh script and returns out of the script

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user logs in by ssh, $SSH_CLIENT will be set in their environment.  So all you need to do is enclose the settings in an `if` statement:

```
if [ "$SSH_CLIENT" ] ; then
    # gsettings set ...
fi
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer. But can't up vote. Says that I require a reputation of 15. Sorry.